# Group over it's center isomorphic to itself means the center is trivial?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ any group, and denote by $Z(G)$ it's center.

If we have $G/Z(G) \cong G$, does this imply $Z(G)$ is trivial?

This is obviously true for $G$ finite; What about the general case?

I want to use this to prove that given two nontrivial groups $G,H$, their free product's center is trivial. To do so, I want to use the universal property of the free product, by choosing the target group as $(G*H)/Z(G*H)$, and the maps

$G \rightarrow (G*H)/Z(G*H), H \rightarrow (G*H)/Z(G*H)$

as

$g \rightarrow gZ(G*H), h \rightarrow hZ(G*H)$.

If $G*H,(G*H)/Z(G*H)$turn out to be isomorphic, I would use the first proposition.

Does this work? If not, how can I prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we let $G$ be an extension of a Prüfer $2$-group $H = {\mathbb Z}(2^\infty)$ by an element $t$ of order $2$ with $t^{-1}ht = h^{-1}$ for all $h \in H$, then $|Z(G)| = 2$ and $G/Z(G) \cong G$.

But in your application, the map $G \to G/Z(G)$ defined by $g \mapsto gZ(G)$ is an isomorphism, which implies immediately that $Z(G)=1$, because $Z(G)$ is the kernel of this map.

Comment: I am looking at the map $G \rightarrow(G*H)/Z(G*H)$ which is not an isomorphism. Do you mean that $G*H \rightarrow G*H/Z(G*H)$ is an isomorphism? How?

Comment: I answered your original question about whether $G/Z(G) \cong G \Rightarrow Z(G)=1$, and the answer to that is no. I cannot see how to prove that $Z(G*H) = 1$ using the method that your are trying to use, and I don't think this is a good way to do it, so I can't help you any more with that.